# Can SharePoint Form/ list be uploaded to another system

Tags: workflow

Can SharePoint forms be uploaded electronically to another system?
Our office uses SharePoint and Infopath forms for client and inter office use.  Would like to know if these items/ SP forms can be uploaded to another system -

Comment: Please define "another system"! Is this another SharePoint farm, or some other kind of system? Is this between two SharePoint farms running the same version or different version of SharePoint?

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding.  The other system is not another SP. The other system is by Ellucian- Banner Document Management system.

Comment: Then the answer is pretty much "no". SharePoint .ASPX forms are not usable as is outside of SharePoint. In general, InfoPath forms can be used with systems other than SharePoint, but you would need to confirm with the other vendor if they are supported .

Comment: Is there an option to host a web page from an external system in your other system? If it is browser based, then it might be possible to use an IFRAME that contains a SharePoint page. That page would still be running in SharePoint and only displayed in the other page.

Comment: Thank you so much for all these comments.  Good idea about hosting another web page- that maybe an option.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following factors

- Whether your external system uses same authentication as in SharePoint (e.g
  windows authentication). May be Single Sign On
- Whether those users have proper access to data connections/relevant
  lists,libraries

  You can upload InfoPath forms to those systems and work seamlessly.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Good points and I will ask our IT about the authentication.